# Yii CJuiDatePicker сбрасывается после апдейта?

Tags: php, yii

> admin.php

```
   $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'name'=>'from_date',  
    'value'=>$defaultarray['from_date'],
    'language' => 'ru',
    'options'=>array(
        'type'=>'POST',
        'update'=>'#content',
        'showAnim'=>'fold',
        'dateFormat'=>'yy-mm-dd',
            'onSelect'=> 'js: function(dateText, inst) {'.
                             CHtml::ajax(array('type'=>'POST','datatype'=>'html','url'=>array('reports_ajax'),
                                        'data'=>array('from_date'=>'js: dateText'),
                                 'update'=>'#content',

                                 )
                                     ).
                '}',
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
    ),
));
```

> модель

```
if($_POST['from_date'])
            $criteria->compare('f_timestamp::date', $_POST['from_date']);
```

> контролер

```
   public function actionReports_ajax()
    {           
        if($_POST['from_date'])
        { 
        $model = new AnalizCreate('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if (isset($_GET['AnalizCreate']))
            $model->attributes = $_GET['AnalizCreate'];

        $content = $this->renderPartial('admin', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));       
        }
    }
```

но при первом выборе получаю

```
<form id="analiz-create-form" class="form-vertical" method="post" action="/mining/analiz/analizCreate/reports_ajax">
<input id="from_date" type="text" name="from_date">
</form>
```

то есть 'карета превратилась в тыкву'. а точнее CJuiDatePicker в текстовое поле. Как победить?

Comment: Для начала вам необходимо создать саму модель, а уже потом можно будет передать данные обычным присваиванием.

Comment: у меня есть модель

Comment: Тогда почему вы ее в коде не используете?

Comment: "Почему страница приходит но не отрисовывается " - заголовок  `Content-Type: text/html` проверьте на наличие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content = $this->renderPartial('admin', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ), false, true);
```